# Class Not Found Exception after slf4j-log4j12 version upgrade to 1.7.36

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, log4j2, slf4j, slf4j-api

After upgrading slf4j-log4j12 version, we are seeing below errors.
Please let us know if anyone has faced the similar issues after upgrade. Appreciate the help!

**Error:**

```
    log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender].
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:190)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:304)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:123)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:755)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:738)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:630)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:516)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:577)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:504)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:119)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Reload4jLoggerFactory.<init>(Reload4jLoggerFactory.java:67)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:72)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:417)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:362)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:388)
    at com.abc.xyz.connect.worker.DistributedConnect.<clinit>(DistributedConnect.java:17)
    log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "stdout".
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.abc.xyz.connect.worker.DistributedConnect).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info
```

-> **Here is the log4j.properties file:**

```
#Root logger option

log4j.rootLogger=INFO,stdout
# configuration to print on console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m %n
```

Maven Dependency Tree Output:

```
>  [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:tree (default-cli) @ kafka-connect ---
>     [INFO] com.abc.xyz:kafka-connect:jar:1.7.1-SNAPSHOT
>     [INFO] +- com.abc.xyz:kafka-clients:jar:1.7.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
>     [INFO] | +- io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:jar:7.1.1:compile
>     [INFO] | | +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.11.0:compile
>     [INFO] | | | +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.12.5:compile
>     [INFO] | | | \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.12.5:compile
>     [INFO] | | | \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.12.5:compile
>     [INFO] | | +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.21:compile
>     [INFO] | | +- io.confluent:kafka-schema-serializer:jar:7.1.1:compile
>     [INFO] | | +- io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-client:jar:7.1.1:compile
>     [INFO] | | | \- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:jar:2.1.10:compile
>     [INFO] | | +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:30.1.1-jre:compile
>     [INFO] | | | +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
>     [INFO] | | | +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
>     [INFO] | | | +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
>     [INFO] | | | +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.8.0:compile
>     [INFO] | | | +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.5.1:compile
>     [INFO] | | | \- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.3:compile
>     [INFO] | | \- io.confluent:common-utils:jar:7.1.1:compile
>     [INFO] | +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:7.1.1-ccs:compile
>     [INFO] | | +- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.5.0-4:runtime
>     [INFO] | | +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.8.0:runtime
>     [INFO] | | \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.8.4:runtime
>     [INFO] | \- com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:jar:7.2.2.jre8:compile
>     [INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.4.0-M1:test
>     [INFO] | +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.0.0:test
>     [INFO] | +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.1.1:test
>     [INFO] | \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.4.0-M1:test
>     [INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.4.0-M1:test
>     [INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.4.0-M1:test
>     [INFO] | \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.4.0-M1:test
>     [INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile
>     [INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-reload4j:jar:1.7.36:compile
>     [INFO] \- ch.qos.reload4j:reload4j:jar:1.2.19:compile
```

Comment: `slf4j-log4j12` version 1.7.36 replaces `log4j` with `reload4j`. If you use Maven, run `mvn dependency:tree` to check what dependencies do you have (and add it to the question).

Comment: The list of dependencies seems correct. Try downloading the jars again with `mvn depenceny:purge-local-repository`.